# Two dimension array and assigning object

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to create two dimensional array and assign objects into it. What's important is, that I want to do this using POINTERS. I want to achieve it like this:

1. Create pointer which will point to array of pointers.
2. Having array pointers I create next 10 cells in memory for example to store there individual object.

This is my code:

I create basic pointer for storing the address for array of pointers:

```
SpecialPoint **arrayOfPointsOnTheMap = NULL;
```

Next I initialize this array:

```
arrayOfPointsOnTheMap = new SpecialPoint*[size];
```

And then create cells in memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < szer; i++) {
    arrayOfPointsOnTheMap[i] = new SpecialPoint[wys];
}
```

And for the end I want to assign object to this newly created array:

```
SpecialPoint *pontInTable;

for (int i = 0; i < szer; i++) {
    pontInTable = arrayOfPointsOnTheMap[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < wys; j++) {
        pontInTable[j] = new SpecialPoint();
    }
}
```

But I get error when trying to create new object int array. I'm a little confused about it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your code either is C or it isn't. In this case it isn't C.

Comment: 1) C and C++ are different languages. Pick the one you use 2) There is no 2D array. `anytype **p;` is not an array and cannot point to a 2D array! A pointer is not an array (and vice versa).

Comment: 1) c is not c++ is not c 2) if you have errors, you should include the error message in your question

Comment: You only use `new` to create pointers, not individual instances as you would in Java. You would want to do `pontInTable[j] = SpecialPoint();`. However, even that is unnecessary; calling `new` already does this by default.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create a 3D array, not a 2D array?

Comment: I know that pointer does not point to array - just I call array in my mind but I know that it isn't in this case. It's 2D array of pointers - Rows (pointers to list of objects) and object inside them. Now it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do in the assignment part is not very clear so I will answer based on my best guess. Let`s say your class is as follows:

```
class SpecialPoint 
{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
    SpecialPoint(int xx, int yy)
    {
        x=xx;
        y=yy;
    }
    SpecialPoint()
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }
};
```

Then you can use the following code to create and initialize your 2d array:

```
    int size = 4;
    int wys = 3;
    SpecialPoint** arrayOfPointsOnTheMap  = new SpecialPoint*[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arrayOfPointsOnTheMap[i] = new SpecialPoint[wys];
    } // you have your array at that point

    SpecialPoint fakePoint(5,6); // create a special point


    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < wys; j++)
        { // Assign your special point instance to all the array cells.
            arrayOfPointsOnTheMap[i][j] = fakePoint;
        }
    }
```

After you are done with the array, do not forget to clean memory using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    delete [] arrayOfPointsOnTheMap[i];
}

delete [] arrayOfPointsOnTheMap;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!